# CUI debugger without browser stuff for NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, node-inspector

I'm looking for a debugger tool for NodeJS, especially for server-side program. If you guys are familiar with ruby, I'm looking for something like pry debugger. To me this sounds like really basic debugging feature to have, so probably I'm jsut missing something.

In short, I want the debugger such that

- stops at `debugger` line
- cui based, so no browser open and stuff
- have basic operations like step in, step out, continue

Here's what I've seen so far:

- node's default debugger (`node debug <js file>`): doesn't stop at `debugger` but stops on every single line
- [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector):
  Opens up browser
- [pryjs](https://github.com/blainesch/pry.js): looks good, but still new, not well used nor tested, and I wasn't satisfied to use

Anybody know good options?

Answer (score 2):

> node's default debugger (node debug ): doesn't stop at debugger but stops on every single line

AFAIK, the builtin debugger can run until a breakpoint is hit (e.g. a `debugger` line). Did you resume the execution via `cont`? It is expected that the debugger stops on the next line after the command `next`.

Also what version of Node are you using? AFAIK there were significant changes in the debugger implementation between v0.10 and v0.12, you may have discovered a bug (a regression).

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yea there probably is, at least I can start default debugger and type 'cont', then it proceeds till the break point.

I was expecting something like killer-solution like pry in ruby, but looks like there's none yet in NodeJS world.

Comment: and sorry didnt answer the last question, im using node 0.12. probably that's why I found it kinda unstable. thanks again for the info